# Using global validation instead method by method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller for example:

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
  [Authorize(Roles = "Administrador, SuperAdmin")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
    }

      [Authorize(Roles = "Administrador, SuperAdmin")]
      public AccountController()
        {
        }

       [Authorize(Roles = "Administrador, SuperAdmin")]
        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {

        }
```

As you can see I add same `Authorize` to each method, and I know if there any way to do a global one that take effect on all of them? Regards

Comment: the "Authorize" tag you have on the head of the controller is enough for all the controller's methods

Comment: but there are no way of use just only one time, like at the top of controller and it bind to all methods? @hdrdiab

Comment: Do you mean several controllers @carl?

Comment: over namespace? @hdrdiab

Comment: try making a new controller containing all your above methods and above this controller put the Authorize tag , and no not above the namespace

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe no-one has properly answered this question for 5 months. Also,  the question has a misleading title. People would come here looking for MVC form *validation*, that is a different concept from *authorization*, which is what this question is about.

The answer is very simple, as indicated in the comments to the question: remove the Authorize attribute from all the methods, and just leave it at the class level - It will then automatically apply to all public methods.

Also, be careful when pasting code to preserve all the proper braces and indentation.

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
   [Authorize(Roles = "Administrador, SuperAdmin")]
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {
       public AccountController()
       {
       }

       public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
       {
       }

       ...
   }
}
```